# ggplot geom_errorbar not in correct location

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R and I've been trying to make barplot with the code below:

## Table

This table is what I'm trying to plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(parallel)
library(devtools)
library(scales)

peak_intersect_rep_elements <-
  tribble(
    ~Sample,                ~CellLine, ~Rep,  ~Total_peaks, ~Alu_intersect, ~L1_intersect, ~Antibody,
    "ADAR062", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   4407,           3329,        201, "p110/p150\nAb1",
    "ADAR062", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   19103,          3481,        8737, "p150\nAb3",
    "ADAR062", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   1782,           836,         109, "p110/p150\nAb4",
    "ADAR112", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   2269,           1852,        61, "p110/p150\nAb1",
    "ADAR112", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   28573,          5725,        17037, "p150\nAb3",
    "ADAR112", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   5115,           4448,        213, "p110/p150\nAb4",
    "ADAR112", "K562",     "rep1",   1367,           770,         49, "p110/p150\nAb1",
    "ADAR112", "K562",     "rep1",   12195,          2889,        5323, "p150\nAb3",
    "ADAR112", "K562",     "rep1",   1178,           656,         58, "p110/p150\nAb4",
    "ADAR004", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   4130,           3289,        136, "p110/p150\nAb1",
    "ADAR004", "HEK293xT", "rep2",   3447,           2816,        135, "p110/p150\nAb1",
    "ADAR004", "HEK293xT", "rep3",   4607,           3697,        176, "p110/p150\nAb1",
    "ADAR004", "HEK293xT", "rep1",   9711,           8450,        373, "p110/p150\nAb4",
    "ADAR004", "HEK293xT", "rep2",   7275,           6163,        294, "p110/p150\nAb4",
    "ADAR004", "HEK293xT", "rep3",   6789,           5704,        256, "p110/p150\nAb4"
  )
```

## Groupby

Here I'm averaging the values together and calculating the standard deviation for the table above.

```
total_peak_intersect_rep_elements_mean <- peak_intersect_rep_elements %>%
  group_by(Sample, CellLine, Antibody, Rep) %>%
  summarise(Mean_total_peaks = mean(Total_peaks), 
            Mean_alu_intersect = mean(Alu_intersect),
            Mean_l1_intersect = mean(L1_intersect),
            SD_total_peaks = sd(Total_peaks),
            SD_alu_intersect = sd(Alu_intersect),
            SD_l1_intersect = sd(L1_intersect)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  replace_na(list(SD_total_peaks = 0, SD_alu_intersect = 0, 
                  SD_l1_intersect = 0))

total_peak_intersect_rep_elements_mean
```

## Plotting bargraph

Here I'm factoring the Rep column into levels and giving them names.

```
temp_plot <- total_peak_intersect_rep_elements_mean %>%
  mutate(Rep = factor(Rep, levels = c("rep1", "rep2", "rep3"),
                      labels = c("s1 (n = 1)", "s2 (n = 1)", 
                                 "s3 (n = 1)")))
```

I'm trying to fill by the Rep column here.

```
temp_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(Antibody, Mean_total_peaks, fill=Rep)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", size = 0.3, color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean_total_peaks - SD_total_peaks, 
                    ymax=Mean_total_peaks + SD_total_peaks), 
                width=0.6, size = 0.8,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_wrap(~CellLine, scales = 'free_x') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("s1 (n = 1)" = "#125863",
                               "s2 (n = 1)" = "#2BA8B3",
                               "s3 (n = 1)" = "#D5E9EB")) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels=comma_format(accuracy = 1)) + 
  labs(y = "ADAR1 IP peaks", x = '', fill = "Replicate") +
  guides(color = F) +
  theme_minimal() +
  NULL
```

After this, I end up with a graph that looks like this.

[image]

However, as stated above, the error bars are not aligning properly. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: have you checked that the temp_plot data frame looks OK?

Comment: Hi George, the data frame looks good to me.

Comment: ive run the code up to that point and all the sd's are zero.  perhaps look at why that is....(edit) your variables in 'group by' seem to uniquely define the observations in the parent set, so there is no variation left.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't want 'sample' in the group_by function

Comment: Thanks, George! It appears 'Sample' in my groupby was the culprit. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the graph! I needed to remove 'Sample' from my group_by statement.